# Understanding the Poincaré Residue in the Context of Algebraic Varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have been trying to understand what exactly the Poincaré residue is in the context of differential forms on algebraic varieties. I see that they occur in other contexts as well.

Let $ f \in \mathbb{C}[z_{1},\dots,z_{n}]. $ If we have an open set $ U_{i} = \Big\lbrace \frac{\partial f}{\partial z_{n}} \neq 0 \Big\rbrace, $ of the hypersurface $ V = \lbrace f=0 \rbrace \subset \mathbb{A}^{n}_{\mathbb{C}}, $ then we have the form $$ \omega_{i} = (-1)^{i}\frac{1}{{\partial f}/{\partial z_{i}}}dz_{1} \wedge \dots \wedge \widehat{dz_{i}} \wedge \dots \wedge dz_{n} \in \Omega^{n-1}(U_{i}). $$

Is this form what the Poincaré residue is? What purposes does it serve?

Comment: Isn't https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_residue clear ? What $n$-form do you start with.

Comment: @reuns Unfortunately, I didn't understand the wikipedia article. I also don't know what the original $ n$-form was. I only remember this form. Sorry, I'm quite short on information on this.

Comment: You have a $n$-rational form $\omega$, for a $n$-(real)-dimensional subset $\lambda$ you can integrate $\int_\lambda \omega$, for a $n-1$-cycle $\gamma$ (a sum of $n-1$ dimensional subsets whose boundaries cancel each other, generalizing the closed loops), let $ T(\gamma)$ be a small "tube" around $\gamma$ (generalizing $Res(f(z),0)=\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{|z|= \epsilon} f(z)dz$), then the poincare residue is the map $ \gamma \mapsto \int_{T(\gamma)} \omega$, which is a $n-1$ cohomology class, under Poincare duality it can be represented by a $n-1$-form $\int_{T(\gamma)} \omega = \int_\gamma \nu$.